# Video upload into server in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Am trying to upload a videos to server. I have two choice to upload videos. First one is, Take video and upload it to server. Second one is, Choose video from photo library and upload it to server.

Step 1:
In this scenario, Take video and upload it to server is working good.

I got the response from server is "Return String: {"jsonstatus":"ok","message":"Thanks for your posting."}".

Now i try to get this video from server. In media_file it says "x.x.x.x/video/96b8954fbed797500da708fd7bad2261video.mov" - I played this video successfully.

Step 2:
But when i choose the video from photo library, it successfully choosed the video. Now i post this video to server.

I got the response from server is "Return String: {"jsonstatus":"ok","message":"Thanks for your posting."}".

Now i try to get this video from server. In media_file it says "Invalid File"

Am using to choose video is,

```
- (IBAction)act_UploadVideoBtn:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,      nil];

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

And Delegate method is,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

//    movieURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
//    
//    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
        // NSLog(@"%@",moviePath);
        movieURL=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
        }
    }

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Give any ideas to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe your server side? So far I understand that this may be a full url problem. Maybe snippets of your json? Perhaps look over your permissions on the folder you are writing into. If you are using ubuntu and lamp as a stack (noob i know) make sure it is r+w, but not exec.

Answer (score 0):

```
//push video path to NSData
NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL];    

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/upload_media.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];  
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"+++++ABck";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data;   
boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"YOURFILENAME\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: video/quicktime\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];//video/quicktime for .mov format
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:webData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary]
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",response);
NSLog(@"%@",error);


/*Server code*/
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$upload_dir['basedir'].'YOUR_DIR']);
```